# How do you load a class that extends jFrame inside a jInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe

Let's say we have 2 classes; classjInternalFrame and classExtjFrame.
As of now, I managed to to set classjInternalFrame's contentPane using classExtjFrame's contents.
I used

`classInternalFrames.setContentPane(new classExtjFrame().getContentPane());`

The problem is, there are radiobuttons and a button in classExtjFrame, and when I click the button, it will check if the radiobuttons are selected or not.

If I don't use jInternalFrame, classExtjFrame will be loaded as a new window and it will work as how it is expected to. But when it is loaded in the jInternalFrame, it will will say it is not selected even though the radiobuttons are selected.

What I think the problem is, when you load the classExtjFrame's components in the jInternalFrame, the names of the radiobuttons will be named as jInternalFrame.radiobutton, something like that. I mean, when it is loaded in jInternalFrame, jInternalFrame will load them as if it's its own.

My goal is, instead of loading the classExtjFrame in a new window, it will be loaded inside a jInternalFrame, or any other container that will let me load the classExtjFrame in it. I'm doing something like MDI in VB6.

I hope I made myself clear. Thank you.

Comment: You should be using a JPanel as a content pane. So simple extend JPanel. There is no need to extend a JInternalFrame and use the getContentPane() method.

Comment: @camickr thank you for your reply. But I think you didn't understand my question, or I don't understand what your answer is. the classExtjFrame is supposed to be standalone, I mean, you can load classExtjFrame and dispose the the mainjFrame(the form where jInternalFrame is located). What I want to do is load the classExtjFrame inside mainjFrame/jInternalFrame..

Comment: This is resolved.

I was doing it the wrong way.
It should be `classExtjFrame = new classExtjFrame();
classInternalFrames.setContentPane(classExtjFrame.getContentPane());`